# knockoutjs conditionally set image src depending from a value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want somehow to set the image source dynamically based on the name value I'm getting from js.

I tried something like this which works for setting the css class of specific div to make it working with image but its not working. What I want to achieve is the src to change dynamically depending from the name value

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src: 'image1.jpg' : Name == 'Package 1', src: 'image2.jpg' : Name == 'Package 2'}" />
```

For reference this is what is working for css styling:

```
<div data-bind="css: { package1_css: Name == 'Package 1', package2_css: Name == 'Package 2'" />
```

Comment: `attr` is attribute you can't use it like `className` inside `css` with conditional check . check the demo here  https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28142/ (switch b/w images)

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed observable for this.

```
self.ImageSource = ko.computed(function(){
    var url1 = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&txt=101&50&w=50&h=50";
    var url2 = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&txt=102&50&w=50&h=50";

    switch(self.Name()){
        case "Package 1":
            return url1;
        case "Package 2":
            return url2;
            break;
    }

}, self);
```

Also, bind to the image tag with the `attr` binding:

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: ImageSource()}" />
```

Comment: I'm getting the items in a list <tbody data-bind="foreach: PremierPacks"> and the name is part of that list @Jezzabeanz

Comment: Well if you add image source to that view model and reference it in the view with $parent.ImageSource. That should work.

Comment: @Laziale well you can pass paramter via function check here https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28144/ . cheers